# Don't return forms in context if they are not altered?

Tags: python, django

In my HTML-file I have a submit button (click_button) to do stuff and a submit button for a Django form (form_submit).
All submits are redirected to one View-function (get_post_from_submit). If using the return render() function, I always have to return the context **including the form**, but I have no information of the form when I pressed the *click_button*.

Is there any way to not return the form again?

home.html

```
....

<body>
{% load bootstrap4 %}
<form action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
</form>



<form action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="click_button" type="submit">Grafik</button>
</form>

</body>
....
```

views.py

```
def get_post_from_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "book_field" in request.POST:
            # Do Stuff
            form = form_book(request.POST)

        if "click_button" in request.POST:
            # Do Stuff
            # Here the form always gets a reset, because I have no Info about the form in POST but it is needed as context...
            form = form_book()

    return render(request, 'home.html',{"form": form})
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your home template please.

Comment: I added the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to encapsulate just one `form` tag across both sections.

```html
<form action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="FormSubmit"/>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Grafik"/>
</form>
```

Using `name="action"` you can differentiate the POST action in the view like so:

```py
def get_post_from_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_book(request.POST)
        if request.POST['action'] == 'FormSubmit':
            [...]

        elif request.POST['action'] == 'Grafik':
            [...]

    return render(request, 'home.html',{"form": form})
```

The `form_book` will no be able to retain the form data whenever the `Grafik` POST type is send to the view.

Comment: This indeed is exactly what i was looking for. Works like a charm! Thank you